# Solspace Freeform: Is there attr:type=“email” for freeform:field tag

Tags: solspace-freeform

I am wondering if you can specify the input type as an attribute in FreeForm.

I would like to give mobile users the right keyboard for the email field e.g. input type="email"

Can this be done on the freeform:field tag?

Thanks.
=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can add "attr:type"](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/form/#variables) to specify the type of the input field.

```
{freeform:field:email
attr:type="email"
attr:class="email-class"
attr:placeholder="Please fill in your email address"
}
```

You can add any attribute you like. Just use it like `attr:name-of-attribute="value of attribute"`

Comment: Thanks. Is there documentation on the Solspace site for all the attr:

Comment: I updated my answer.